# Monetizing an API, View the invoice via the API Developer Portal, Dynamic Rate,(WSO2 version 4.2.0)

Tags: wso2, stripe-payments, wso2-api-manager

After successfully configuring my Stripe and WSO2 API Manager accounts, I created a dynamic rate subscription for my API and linked it accordingly. The API monetization was set up, and when I sent usage data using Postman, everything worked smoothly. However, upon attempting to view the invoice, a popup window appeared with the message 'No Data Available' and 'Pending invoice data not found for this subscription'.

Error :

```
ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.APIIdentifier org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.SubscribedAPI.getApiId()'
        at org.wso2.apim.monetization.impl.StripeMonetizationImpl.getCurrentUsageForSubscription(StripeMonetizationImpl.java:1285) ~[org.wso2.apim.monetization.impl-1.4.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl.subscriptionsSubscriptionIdUsageGet(SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl.java:478) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.SubscriptionsApi.subscriptionsSubscriptionIdUsageGet(SubscriptionsApi.java:188) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) ~[?:?]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:116) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:165) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.7.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:106) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:67) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.76.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

I initially used version 4.2.0 and attempted to view the invoice multiple times without success. Later, I switched to version 4.1.0, which resolved the issue. I'm still hopeful to find a solution with version 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about WSO or any of the other aspects, but my guess would be that if you dig into this you'd find that it's related to the change in the Stripe API version whereby to charge an Invoice you create the Invoice object first and then add the items to it; in older versions you create the InvoiceItems first and then an Invoice, which "pulls in" the floating items.

[https://docs.stripe.com/upgrades#2022-08-01:~:text=The-,pending_invoice_items_behavior,-parameter%20on](https://docs.stripe.com/upgrades#2022-08-01:%7E:text=The-,pending_invoice_items_behavior,-parameter%20on)

Comment: it's probably not a problem with Stripe. i read the documentation, but there was nothing related to the error.